# Query other database's INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, information-schema

I have a shared database that stores procedures for all the other databases on the same server. This helps maintain one instance of a procedure rather than copying it across all databases. As long as I prepend `DBName` to all my tables, i.e. `SELECT * FROM DBName.Table`, I've been able to successfully have a shared repository for procedures.

However, I've run into an instance where I need to reference `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables, but the shared database only has tables for that database. Is there a concept of querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` on another database?

I'd like to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

`SELECT * FROM [DBName].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Comment: The `I_S.TABLES` table has the `TABLE_SCHEMA` column, which is the database the table belongs to. There is only one `I_S` - it is a *virtual* database. The problem might be with rights as RJ's answer shows.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you need:

```
CREATE
    DEFINER = root
    PROCEDURE ...
    SECURITY INVOKER   -- This limits what the proc can do to what the user is GRANTed
    BEGIN ... END
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
select tables_name from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA="sys" limit 1;
```

The sys is the database name for search in.